# How to keep date input everytime I leave page and go back again (Streamlit)?

Tags: session-state, streamlit

I make a streamlit app and it involves st.date_input widget in one page. When I go to the second page and go bak to the first page, the widget restarts and I must select the date again.The data I have involves data from 2022 and I do not want to re-click from 2023 to 2022. I'm trying to use the session-state app but I'm lost.

```
"""

import streamlit as st
import datetime

def start(year, month, day):
   if "start" not in st.session_state:
    
      st.session_state.start = datetime.date(year, month, day)


start_date = st.date_input('Select date(s)', key="start")

s_year = start_date.year
s_month = start_date.month
s_day = start_date.day

start(s_year, s_month, s_day)
```

"""

I tried this method but it still resets to the current day. I don't want the widget to reset. I want the widget to be still.

Answer (score 0):

To store the value of your `st.date_input` widget in session state, you actually don't need most of the code. Every widget with a key is automatically added to session state, so you can just do:

```
start_date = st.date_input('Select date(s)', key='start')
```

Then you'll be able to access the value in session state via the following:

```
st.write(st.session_state['start'])
```

The problem is that when widgets aren't rendered on a page, their keys are deleted from session state. This means that when you navigate to a different page in your app, the session state value gets deleted. To get around this, you can maintain a list of widget keys that you want to "save" and add something like the following to each page:

```
for key in 'global_widget_keys':
    st.session_state[key]=st.session_state[key]
```

[This thread](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/preserving-state-across-sidebar-pages/107/23) has a longer explanation of what I've summarized above.